# Should I use a single procedure for multiple operations, or split them into multiple procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing stored procedures for several operations in a database, I just wanted to know:

- Is it better to design a single procedure for a table which can perform add, modify, delete operations or...
- Should I design seperate procedures for each operations

Which approach would be better?

Comment: Ashok, please try to take an extra couple of seconds before you submit your question. Remember, in order to get the best answers possible, it is better to give your question a descriptive title and write it down in a way that makes it easy to understand the actual question within seconds. Thanks.

Comment: I will take care of ur advice from next time.
Thanks

Comment: @Ashok: Is any of the answers below an answer to your question? If so, you should mark one of them as the answer. If not, you can of course leave the question open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that a separate stored procedure for each operation is best. Otherwise you get too much logic inside your procedures.

Besides, most operations require different parameters. For a delete you only need the primary key but for an insert you must provide values all not nullable columns. You do not want to provide dummy insert parameters when you just want to delete a record.

Answer (score 2):

At a minimum you'd need several SQL commands with if ... else logic. Stored procedures are, I find, much easier to manage if they do exactly one thing.

It's a transferable concept from normal procedural development, but it applies even more strongly to stored procedures.

Benefits: Easier to test, more meaningful SP names (e.g. UpdateCustomer rather than CustomerHandler), less coupling/better cohesion, simpler procedures, fewer arguments.

Answer (score 0):

One operation per procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you love Uncle Bob: [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 0):

It is best to implement different procedures for different logics.

This way, you can easily manage code and reduce dependencies.