# Are there any advantages in using a single stored procedure for multiple operations or is my teacher wrong?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on my databases class final project, which consists of making an application that can access and do operations in a database. My teacher insists that I should use a single stored procedure per table:

```
--In stored procedure "sp_Ciudades"
    @Opcion int,
    @IdCiudad int = NULL,
    @IdEstado int = NULL,
    @Nombre varchar(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    --Create new record
    IF @Opcion = 1
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Ciudades
            VALUES(@IdEstado, @Nombre)
        END
    --Delete record
    IF @Opcion = 2
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM Ciudades
            WHERE IdCiudad = @IdCiudad
        END
    --Update city
    IF @Opcion = 3
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Ciudades
            SET IdEstado = @IdEstado
                Nombre = @Nombre
            WHERE IdCiudad = @IdCiudad
        END
    --Retrieve cities
    IF @Opcion = 4
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM Ciudades
            WHERE IdCiudad = @IdCiudad OR @IdCiudad = 0 OR @Ciudad IS NULL
        END
    --Fill cities ComboBox
    IF @Opcion = 5
        BEGIN
            SELECT IdCiudad, Nombre
            FROM Ciudades
            ORDER BY Nombre
        END
END
```

On the other hand I tried to do something like this:

```
--In stored procedure "sp_Ciudades_Vista"
    @IdCiudad int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Ciudades
    WHERE IdCiudad = @IdCiudad OR @IdCiudad = 0 OR @IdCiudad IS NULL
    ORDER BY ID
END
```

```
--In stored procedure "sp_Ciudades_Cambio"
    @IdCiudad int,
    @IdEstado int,
    @Nombre varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Ciudades
    SET IdEstado = @IdEstado,
        Nombre = @Nombre
    WHERE IdCiudad = @IdCiudad
END
```

I feel the code is much more organized (and encapsulated) and easier to read and understand when defining the command strings in my application (with the numeric options I constantly have to go back to the procedure definition in order to see what each number does). Also, I only use the parameters that are needed to achieve the operation.

However, my teacher says that if I do it this way, the database will have way too many stored procedures since *in a real database, there are over 200 options per procedure, and the database may even crash if there's too many procedures in it*.

I have already read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728679/should-i-use-a-single-procedure-for-multiple-operations-or-split-them-into-mult) and the most voted answer states that:

> [...] a separate stored procedure for each operation is best. Otherwise you get too much logic inside your procedures.

But my teacher still insists I should be doing it the other way. Is my teacher's argument true?
What are the **advantages** of having **multiple** options/operations inside a **single** stored procedure?

Comment: Technically, your teacher is correct since that is how you will be graded. One can argue this approach either way. Suggest you read about coupling and cohesion. I personally disagree with this approach - and to see better why create Ca procedure for a table with many columns. Certainly `@opcion` shouldn't be an int since you cannot possible have 2 billion options. The other defaults are generally nonsense as well - that only encourages lazy coding IMO.

Comment: @Larnu Read again - _a single stored procedure per table_ which is what OP posted.

Comment: I see, it's the ambiguous wording, @Smor . I read that the OP thinks that they should have "catch all" procedure, that handles many tables.

Comment: I disagree with the teacher. A procedure should be doing a single operation; not hiding many. Using seperate procedures to `INSERT`, `UPDATE` (or Upsert) and `DELETE` are my preference. I will also, admit, having some kind of `int` value that denotes that operation is not exactly user friendly unless you have good documentation.

Comment: The only benefit I see to such a Swiss army knife procedure is that, if your table definition changes, you only have to update one procedure, and if you miss a column it'll generally be obvious. But the drawbacks are significant: it's not clear which column(s) are used in each operation (a `DELETE` will only use or need the key, but why not match on the other columns too?), the parameter that holds the operation is cryptic (who will remember exactly what kind of select option 4 or 5 is?) and you lose the ability to secure individual operations (user X should be able to select but not delete).

Comment: Some procedures called `dbo.UserDetails` `dbo.NewUser`, `dbo.UpdateUser` and `dbo.RemoveUser` is much more clear what that do than one called `dbo.ManagerUsers` and then a parameter with the value `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4` might `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE` that user, with a bunch of optional parameters (as the user's name or their DoB is irrelevant when you want to `DELETE` them, for example).

Comment: *"there are over 200 options per procedure, and the database may even crash if there's too many procedures in it."* it'll crash at a mere *200* procedures? Well, my server will have crashed years ago then; one of the database probably has close to ***10,000*** procedures. Without offence to your teacher, that claim is outrageously wrong.

Comment: Purely for academic purposes, the actual limit on the number of stored procedures is the limit on the number of objects, which, in total, can't exceed 2 147 483 647 (2^31-1). So while there is a limit (shared by all objects, so tables, views, triggers etcetera), hitting it in an actual database would almost certainly require a deliberate attempt at breaking things. Your teacher may have been thinking about front-ends like Management Studio crashing; those are fare more likely to hit limits when large lists of objects have to be presented. As a real-world argument it's poor.

Comment: All in all, this looks like the kind of approach that is not actually one most people would use in real life, for all the reasons presented above, but one that your teacher has convinced themselves is a good idea and is now, for better or worse, teaching. Your best bet is to acknowledge this, conform to the exercise, and use it as a learning experience without actually adopting this approach yourself later.

Comment: One reason to use SPs is to isolate the application from the underlying data structures. Something like `AddUser` makes sense and may not need to change when you realize that a user may have more than one telephone number, hence splitting a `Users` table into `Users` and `UserTelephoneNumbers`. It can validate the data before affecting one or more tables. It can function without the caller having write access to the underlying tables. It can verify authority, e.g. are you the user's manager, log changes, ... . And don't use the `sp_` prefix.

Comment: Better question is whether you should be writing this code at all. For basic single row CRUD operations, use an ORM attached to your client code. A stored procedure should be when you are doing multiple operations as one,

Comment: Use this as a learning experience... the "experts" are often quite wrong. Especially in academia, where the professor likely has never developed a production system for a customer/business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Are there any advantages**? Probably - opening Management Studio could be quicker.

**Is your teacher wrong**? Yes, most certainly, but as SMor and Jeroen write in the comments: Your teacher does the grading, so he's right until you graduate your class.

Take a look at this question: [Generic Stored Procedure for ALL the tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179431/create-a-generic-procedure-which-inserts-data-into-any-table)

If you could write a single stored procedure for each table with Create, Read, Update and Delete, then why not build a single generic stored procedure with CRUD operations for ALL the tables? One database - One stored procedure.

Now, apply the logic you would use to determine that this is a bad idea to your problem.

Or apply SOLID principles - they apply to stored procedures as well. You wouldn't write a single method to do 4 wildly different operations based on an input parameter, would you?

Or have a look here: [If logic in stored proc](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185252/sql-server-if-logic-in-stored-procedure-and-the-plan-cache).

On first execution SQL Server will explore all the branches, and build a plan - but it will use the parameters seen at that first execution. So assume your first execution is an insert with @IdCiudad = null, then that's what SQL Server will optimize for in the option 4 branch.

Your initial insert will build a select plan (for option 4) where all rows are expected to be returned, meaning a too large memory grant and maybe a parallel plan with hash joins to boot.

Oh, and

```
WHERE Foo = @foo OR @foo = 0 OR @foo IS NULL
```

SQL Server won't know how to optimize for this. See Aaron Bertrands article here [Kitchen sink design pattern](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example).